# Tag migration and sharing from many sites

Tags: support, tags

I have saved some interesting tags on Programmers SE and some on Stack Overflow. Is the platform capable of copying/updating/merging such tags from one SE site to another?

Server Fault: [unix](/questions/tagged/unix), [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), etc.
Stack Overflow: [unix](/questions/tagged/unix), [c](/questions/tagged/c)

I'm asking if it's possible to merge a selectable behaviour linux tag into Stack Overflow, without manually entering all tags from Server Fault into other SE sites, for example Stack Overflow, Programmers SE and Super User.

Answer (score 2):

Correct, you should be using tag sets:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood the question correctly, it's not possible to migrate your interesting tags between sites.

However, you can create what's called a "tag set" at http://stackexchange.com -- this allows you to see an aggregation of questions from multiple sites on the Stack Exchange network.